# Forcing a new Id on an event insert

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the Google Calendar API and I'm copying an event from one calendar to another like this:

```
CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = this.ApplicationName
            });
CalendarListResource.ListRequest calRequest = service.CalendarList.List();
calRequest.MinAccessRole = CalendarListResource.ListRequest.MinAccessRoleEnum.Owner;
CalendarList calendars = calRequest.Execute();
CalendarListEntry selectedCalendar = calendar.Items[0];

EventsResource.ListRequest eventRequest = service.Events.List(selectedCalendar.Id);
eventRequest.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
eventRequest.ShowDeleted = false;
eventRequest.SingleEvents = true;
eventRequest.MaxResults = 50;
eventRequest.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
Events events = eventRequest.Execute();

Event currentEvent = events.Items[0];
EventsResource.InsertRequest copyRequest = service.Events.Insert(currentEvent, calendarToCopyTo.Id);
copyRequest.Execute();
```

It works great....the first time. The second time, it throws an error because the event Id is no longer unique on the `calendarToCopyTo` (even if I delete the event that was just created and try it again). My question is: how can I force a new Id to be generated on the event that I'm "inserting"? I've tried `currentEvent.Id = "";` before these lines, but that didn't seem to work.

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The requested identifier already
>   exists. [409] Errors [ Message[The requested identifier already
>   exists.] Location [ - ] Reason[duplicate] Domain[global] ]

According to this [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) (the .NET one), I should probably just create a new `Event` object (based off `currentEvent`), then send that as the parameter to the Insert request. So another question here is: what is the easiest way to copy all the properties from one `Event` variable (here being `currentEvent`) to another?

Comment: can you remove the id from the currentEvent object?  or possibly clone the object into a new object so that the id is removed?  this sounds like a weird bug to me.  Google should be creating the ID when upon insert I would think and ignoring any id that you send.   What is the exact error you are getting please?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping Google would create a new Id for the new event on the `calendarToCopyTo` every time (regardless of the Id of the event you send in). The exact message of the exception is this: `Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError The requested identifier already exists. [409] Errors [ Message[The requested identifier already exists.] Location [ - ] Reason[duplicate] Domain[global] ]` . https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors tells me that I need to generate a new ID and I'm not sure how to do that (other than creating a new `Event` object)

Comment: can you post the rest of your code how are you currentEvent?

Comment: @DaImTo I updated the question with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've learned (and the solution I've come up with):

First off, if you want to use my code that I had above, you would have to call both of these lines before the copyRequest is initialized:

```
currentEvent.Id = "";
currentEvent.ICalUID = "";
```

(because the `Id` and `ICalUID` are both used as Ids, so both have to be reset). **Important note here:** if you're going to later call something like an UpdateRequest with currentEvent, there will be problems because you cleared the Id of that object (because UpdateRequest requires the eventId as a parameter - so even if you saved it from before, you'd have to "re-set" the Id and ICalUID again before initializing that request). [The ICalUID is essentially equal to `Id + "@google.com"`]

**My solution:**

Rather than save the Id and ICalUID, clear it, copy the event, then set them back before my UpdateRequest, I created a clone method for cloning an Event:

```
private Event clone(Event eventToClone)
{
    Event result = new Event();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Event).GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.CanRead)
            property.SetValue(result, property.GetValue(eventToClone, null));
    }

    return result;
}
```

So now my code for copying an event to another calendar just becomes this:

```
Event newEvent = clone(currentEvent);
newEvent.Id = "";
newEvent.ICalUID = "";
EventsResource.InsertRequest copyRequest = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarToCopyTo.Id);
copyRequest.Execute();
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try catch, so if not exist then it will create, else, it will update, like this:

```
try
{
    service.Events.Insert(newEvent, calendarId).Execute();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    service.Events.Update(newEvent, calendarId, newEvent.Id).Execute();
}
```

In my solution it works perfectly.